# c++ will `map::key_comp` hamper performance if called as a way to compare a number with existing key?

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++11, functional-programming

i have a type defined as below,

```
using BookMapT = std::map<long long int, long long int, std::function<bool(long long int,long long int)>>;
BookMapT greater_map(greater<long long int>{});
BookMapT less_map(less<long long int>{});
```

So if have a number and I want to compare with the beginning of a `BookMapT`

```
int compare(BookMapT& book, long long int number_to_compare){
    return book.key_comp()(number_to_compare, book.begin()->first);
}
```

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/key_comp/ I can see `key_comp` return a `copy` of the comparison object, will this `copy` action somehow hamper performance?
What confuse me most is how much cost is this copying of `std::function` ?

Thanks.

Comment: The two comparators you are using are stateless, there is no data being copied, so making copies of them is very negligible overhead.

Comment: On a side note, the code shown would be a lot cleaner to read and manage if you use an alias for `long long int`, such as `std::int64_t` or at least a custom `using`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

typedef std::function<bool(long long int,long long int)> TF;

TF cp(const TF & f) { return f; }

int cp1(TF f, int times, int n) {
    int c = 0;

    for(int i = times; --i >= 0;) {
        c += cp(f)(i, n);
    }

    return n;
}

int cp2(TF f, int times, int n) {
    int c = 0;

    for(int i = times; --i >= 0;) {
        c += TF(f)(i, n);
    }

    return n;
}

int no_cp(TF f, int times, int n) {
    int c = 0;

    for(int i = times; --i >= 0;) {
        c += f(i, n);
    }

    return n;
}

typedef int(*TP)(TF, int, int);

void test(TP p, int n)
{
    double s = 0;
    int c = 0;
    for(int i = 10; --i >= 0;) {;
        auto t = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        c += (*p)(std::less<long long int>{}, 50000000, n);
        std::chrono::duration<double> d = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - t;
        s += d.count();
    }
    std::cout << s / 10 << "(" << c << ")" <<  std::endl;
}

int main() {
    int n = static_cast<int>(std::random_device()());
    std::cout << "cp1: ";
    test(&cp1, n);
    std::cout << "cp2: ";
    test(&cp2, n);
    std::cout << "no_cp: ";
    test(&no_cp, n);
}
```

Results with `-O0` flag:

cp1: 2.24382

cp2: 2.10708

no_cp: 0.833974

Results with `-O3` flag:

cp1: 0.20065

cp2: 0.199159

no_cp: 0.0643156

---

CPU: Intel Core i7 (Comet Lake)